# Carousel error in fragment

Tags: android

I have added carouselPicker in the fragment but at

```
CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this,itemsImages,0);
```

It is showing me error

> Error:(85, 98) error: incompatible types: FragmentAction cannot be
>   converted to Context.

How to fix this problem

## FragmentAction.java

```
package com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
//import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.R;
import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.Registration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentAction#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentAction extends Fragment  {

    CarouselPicker carouselPicker1;


    private static final String KEY_MOVIE_TITLE = "key_title";

    public FragmentAction() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentAction.
     */
    public static FragmentAction newInstance(String movieTitle) {
        FragmentAction fragmentAction = new FragmentAction();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE, movieTitle);
        fragmentAction.setArguments(args);

        return fragmentAction;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action,container,false);
        CarouselPicker carouselPicker1 = (CarouselPicker)v.findViewById( R.id.carouselPicker1 );
        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> itemsImages = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.website_design));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.digital_marketing));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.domain_registration));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.graphic));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.mob));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.server));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.software_development));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.marketing));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.ssl));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.domain_registration));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.domain_registration));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.domain_registration));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this,itemsImages,0);
        carouselPicker1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        ImageButton imageButton =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.movie_icon);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(), Registration.class ) );
            }
        });

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Drawable movieIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.webdesign, getContext().getTheme());
       // if (movieIcon != null) {
          //  movieIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.pink), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        //}
        ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_icon)).setImageDrawable(movieIcon);

        String movieTitle = getArguments().getString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_title)).setText(movieTitle);

    }


}
```

Comment: `CarouselViewAdapter` constructor expects that you pass it a `Context` as `st parameter, while you are passing a `Fragment` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to

```
CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this.getContext(),itemsImages,0);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanx it  helped :D